# Master Page in Asp.net is not loading with code implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am new to asp.net! by following a tutial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUx2Bdx68f4 i have written code that built successfully! But it showed following error as i executed this:
[image]

***Style Sheet***

```
body
{
    font-family: 'lucida grande' ,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
#wrapper
{
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    border: 5px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#banner
{
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
    background-image:url(../Styles/kk.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;   
}
#navigation
{
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-image:url(../Styles/kk.jpg);
}
#content_area
{
    float: left;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
}
#sidebar
{
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height:400px;
    margin:20px 10px 20px 10px;
    border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
}
#footer
{
    clear:both;
    width: auto;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-image:url(../Styles/kk.jpg);
}
```

***Master Page Code***

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel= "StyleSheet1" type="text/css" href ="~/Style/StyleSheet1.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="banner">
    </div>
    <ul id="navigation">
    </ul>
    <div id="content_area">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <p> All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: It is not an error it is directory listing. you need to add at least one aspx page in solution and set this page as start page of the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Master page is not directly excuted, you need to create aspx page, then include that master page in it.

Set that aspx page as a startup page, then execute the program.

For adding master page:

Your @page directive should have attribute as `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"`

Your whole @page directive should look something like following:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="c#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ASPXPageName.aspx.cs" Inherits="NamespaceName.ASPXPageName" %>
```

It will have following steps while adding aspx:

[image]

[image]

Can follow below Doccument:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to add at least one normal `aspx` page and it may use your master page. Master Page is not browsable by itself.

Right click on your project `Add -> New Item -> Web From using Master Page` select your master page and view your newly created page.

Comment: @user2835256 You have to add quotes between path to image: `background-image:url("../Styles/kk.jpg");`

Answer (score 1):

Have you created any view for master page. Create one view and then run that aspx page using f5(debug) or ctrl+f5